# Observer? design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have

```
public class mammal implements Imammle
{

    public String getName() {
        return "Mammal";
    }

    public String speak() {
        return getName() +  "Maaaauuu";
    }

}
```

I need to know when my animal makes a sound so that I can take corresponding actions in real time like eat feed.
What kind of design pattern should I use?
Thanks.

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it was not clear.

Comment: I see answer to your question in title

Answer (score 9):

The [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design pattern could possibly be used to solve your problem. In the Observer Pattern, there are two distinct types of objects:

1. **Observer** objects are objects that want to be notified whenever Observable objects change.
2. **Observable** objects are objects that can be watched by Observers

**Observers** are registered with the **Observable** objects they wish to watch. Whenever an **Observable** object changes, it notifies all of the **Observers** that have been registered with it.

Based on your code example I am going to assume you are using Java. In that case you can use [Observer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and [Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) to reduce the number of changes you have to make to your existing code.

```
public class mammal extends java.util.Observable implements Imammle
{

    public String getName() {
        return "Mammal";
    }

    public String speak() {
        setChanged(); // We have been changed
        notifyObservers(); // Notify everyone that we have changed
        return getName() +  "Maaaauuu";
    }

}
```

Now we create a class that wishes to watch for when something changes:

```
public class Watcher implements java.util.Observer
{
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Something has changed");
    }
}
```

Finally, we register our watcher(s) with a `mammal` so that they can be informed whenever it changes.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        mammal cow = new mammal();
        Watcher farmer = new Watcher();
        cow.addObserver(farmer);
        cow.speak();
    }
}
```

There are a number of draw-backs to this approach:

1. Observers can be registered with any Observable object. You may wish for your Observer to only be able to observe `mammal`s. On the flip side, you may wish for only certain kinds of Observers to be able to observe a `mammal`.
2. There really isn't any way for your `Observer` to know what exactly changed with the `mammal` without

   - The `mammal` passing in some kind of message to the Observer using the [notifyObservers(Object arg)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers(java.lang.Object)) method
   - OR the Observer checking a public flag set in the `mammal`

If either of these drawbacks is a problem for you, then you may want to avoid `Observer` and `Observable` and look into modifying your existing classes (`mammal` and whatever your `Observers` are) to implement their own, application-specific methods.